# How to stop page redirection after firebase update

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

Here is my submit function

```
Submit(value,imagevalue,event)
  {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
              window.plugins.toast.show("Please wait...", "short",'bottom',3000);
        });
    var imagevalue1=imagevalue;
    var Result =  moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    this.Editflat.controls['UPDATEDDATE'].setValue(Result); 
    var v=this.Editflat.value;
     this.af.database.list('/flats').update(this.key,v);

}
```

Here is my code

```
<form [formGroup]="Editflat"  novalidate>
         <ion-item>
             <ion-label floating>About flat</ion-label>
             <ion-textarea class="textareadesc" elastic formControlName="ABOUT_FLAT">
             </ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>
           <div class="btn"  >
             <button ion-button full type='submit'  (click)="Submit(Editflat,images,$event)">Update</button>
         </div>

    </form>
```

I update the data into firebase thereafter page redirect to root page without push.why?

How can i fix this issue?

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: do you have something in the `action` part of your `<form>` tag that is sending the form somewhere/redirecting?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.No, i do not have any action in form.I update my code.Kindly check.

Comment: I tried to many ways.But I don't know why the page is redirected to root page.

Comment: what happens if in your `Submit` function you do `event.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: I also tried event.preventDefault().It's working fine on without firebase update.when I update to firebase.It's not working.: (

Comment: and if you attach a `.then(res => console.log('updated with', res))` to the firebase update operation, does it show something?

Comment: I consoled.and the value is undefined.Here is my output "updated with undefined".But the values are updated to firebase.

Comment: @crash can u help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147785/discussion-between-crash-and-anisundar).